# Get gem versions from external ruby installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have two isolated Ruby installations (one for Chef, one for Sensu). From within the Chef installation, I'd like to get a list of all versions of a gem installed into the Sensu ruby. I know the absolute paths of both installations at runtime.

I've used `Gem::Specification::find_all_by_name` before to great effect, and this is the sort of method I'm looking for, but it only seems to work on the *currently executing ruby*, and doesn't seem to have any kind of notion of reusability.

One way would be to use `gem list` with `grep` and parse that output, but i'd really rather not have to shell out to solve the problem, I prefer an in-ruby solution. I could also inspect the filesystem myself and recreate the logic of `Gem::Specification`, but that's not that much better than shelling out.

Is there a way to get equivalent output to `Gem::Specification` without duplicating the parsing logic myself?

Answer (score 0):

`Gem::Specification` has a (global) property called [`dirs`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-c-dirs-3D) which allows you to specify an array of paths that `Gem::Specification` will use when searching for specifications.

Note that the path it expects must be the parent folder of "specifications", so for instance `/opt/embedded/product/lib/specifications` will not work, but `/opt/embedded/product/lib` *will* work.